# Double - Reverse proxy NGINX

Tags: nginx, proxy, nginx-faq

Как правильно передать реальный ip адрес клиента при такой схемы работы?

main nginx server (M)-> balancer nginx server (B) -> app python (APP)

main nginx server (M)- главный сервер , крутится на nginx и все запросы проксирует через опцию proxy_pass балансирующему серверу (B), который дальше проксирует запросы непосредственно в приложение (APP).
Проблема в том не получается с (M) передать реальный ip клиента на (B)  с последующей передачи адреса в (APP).
Как заставить (B)  принять не Host от (M), а адрес из заголовка X-Real-IP ?
В моем случаи в (APP) приходит ip сервера  (B), а не реальный адрес клиента. 
Если убираю (B) то в (APP) без проблем отдаю ip клиента через X-Real-IP

Comment: #server_B 
http {
set_real_ip_from 0.0.0.0/0;
real_ip_header X-Real-IP;
real_ip_recursive on;
...
}

Comment: спасибо буду пробовать